# Layouts changing drastically in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have This [site](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html) 
It looks okay in normal browser from PC. 
But whenever I switch to mobile view from inspect, it looks like this 
http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/

[2](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSHAe.png 
Should I implement Media screen indivisually for all components in website? 
If Yes, then Why is title and some components are fit in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement media screen for every item present. the trick is to make it responsive from the ground up, and then just make small alterations to the layout as it shrinks down if still needed. For example, take this news_area div section. You have it positioned in the center of its parent container - news_contents. But dont use fixed margins to center it, you want add css so that it stays in the center even when it shrinks down.

example:

```
.news_contents {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#news_area {
    width: 90%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    margin: 30px auto!important;
}
```

[note:the !important tag is only needed here to override some of your existing css. Also this is just a rough example to show you the layout.]

With this added to your css, the news_area will always be centered in its parent div, and always have space either side. This is what i mean by coding it with a responsive design from the start. This section now doesn't need media screen to alter it again as it works on all device sizes with its original css.